# Elegant way for a singleton to reference itself in JS/coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm creating a module consisting of a singleton designed to store data:

```
context =
    c:@
    selected:
        sketch: undefined
        points: []
        edges: []
    hovered:
        points: []
        edges: []
    ###Note: Perhaps later I can make a more elegant naming scheme
    say, specifying subobjects such as context.select.sketch(<sketch>)###
    select:
        sketch: (sketch)->
            c.selected.sketch = sketch
            return
        node: (point)->
            c.selected.points.push point
    deselectAll: ->
        ###Clear all arrays ###
        c.selected.points.length = 0
        c.selected.edges.length = 0
```

I want select to contain methods for accessing attributes inside the `selected` sub-object. However, unlike a closure, I can't store `this` inside a named variable, and I can't access `context` from within `context.select` as `this` will refer to `context.select`

How can I establish a reference to the parent/root object for use within sub-objects?

Comment: Did you try to use `context.selected.sketch` instead of `c.selected.sketch`?

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to create classes with no namespaces for improved readability. Here you are, thou:

```
# please use class syntax as a vessel to create singleton
# you may declare class and then call new and assign it's instance to avariable 
# or, since it's a singleton, you can do that in one line
window.Context = new class Context

# constructor function should init the object
constructor: ->
    @selected =
      sketch: undefined
      points: []
      edges: []
    @hovered =
      points: []
      edges: []

    # convenience namespace, just referring to class methods
    @select =
      sketch: @selectSketch
      node: @selectNode

  # not having namespaces adds a lot to clarity of the class
  selectSketch: (sketch) =>
    # no need to call return here
    @selected.sketch = sketch

  selectNode: (point) =>
    @selected.points.push point

  # you probably want to assign new array rather then reset the length 
  deselectAll: =>
    @selected.points = []
    @selected.edges = []
```

Comment: I love this, it's elegant and does exactly what I want it to do. Is there an advantage to doing it this way versus creating an IIAF which returns an object of interface functions? That's what it brings to mind.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by IIAF? Anyway, if I understand the question right: class syntax is preferred in Coffeescript, ES6 and Typescript. This is great step forward versus just creating objects. It both gives you structure and normalizes object creation. Also, you can extend classes etc (http://coffeescript.org/#classes). And it was the feature that made a lot of developers move to CoffeeScript few years ago.

Comment: I'll read into it more! To be honest, I've been using coffeescript as javascript shorthand and haven't taken too much time to learn the unique features and design patterns of the language. IIAF=immediately invoked anonymous function. Sinc e asking the question, I've looked at what `class` actually compiles to, and it appears to be just what I described! (Though certainly much more concise.